# jquery multi select box check whether elements present or not

Tags: jquery

How to check whether multiple select box contains any element or not.In this case there are no elements in the multiselect box.I tried the following.I get an error at `selected_available_segments.length` as null

```
<select multiple id="selected_available_segments"> 
</select>
```

Jquery

```
  var selected_available_segments = $("#selected_available_segments").val();    
  if ($('#selected_available_segments').size() != 0) {
   for(var i =0; i< selected_available_segments.length;i++)
    {
        alert("Got it");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `option` size of the list:

```
if ($("#selected_available_segments option").length) {
    console.log("Im there!");
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Tp4EB/

Comment: If it resolved your issue you should click on the check to make clear it is solved. Thanks.

Comment: There is a time restriction please wait

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = $('#selected_available_segments option').length;

if (options){
    for(var i = 0; i < options; i++)
    {
        alert("Got it");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the `if(options)`, the `for` loop's `i<options` takes care of that.

Comment: @nnnnnn I guess you're right. I thought at first that there was a `if else` statement

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#selected_available_segments').is(':empty') === false) {
    //
}
```

or

```
if (!$('#selected_available_segments').is(':empty')) {
    //
}
```

(However, i find it's easy to miss the `!` here, so I prefer my first solution.)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KARN2/1/